# Best practise on appending new data to a dataframe

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

In my workflow, I am getting new data coming in daily and then I look to add these to a data frame. I am wondering what the most optimal way to do this (basically the best pattern, I am using PySpark with AWS Glue with s3).

The pattern at the moment I am thinking of is:

grab new data (df1) -> union with old dataset (df1 & df2 = df3) & then drop duplicates (df3) -> then union de-duplicated dataset with old dataset (df3 & df2 = df4) and then overwrite (df4 overwrites df2)

I am wondering if there is a better pattern to follow.

Also is it better to overwrite old datasets or delete this dataset and then save a new dataset, the code I have inherited has both patterns in the code at different points

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate the variance between df1 and df2, and save those distinctions in your table. Consequently, only the variations will be appended in the end